# Android: Got right lat and long but markers are printed at the wrong place

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I'm fetching all the 's stores in "Göteborg" and adding a marker on my mapView.
The problem is that with this code my markers get all bunched up in Africa.

I've checked that coordinates is correct so it isnt that.

Anyone know what's the problem is?

```
    df = ((ClassHandler)getApplication()).getStoreDatabadeFacade();

    Cursor plotstore = df.getAllStorePos("Göteborg");
    startManagingCursor(plotstore);
    plotstore.moveToFirst();

    while(plotstore.isAfterLast() == false){

        GeoPoint addStore = new GeoPoint(plotstore.getColumnIndex("lat"), plotstore.getColumnIndex("long"));
        //OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(addStore, plotstore.getString(plotstore.getColumnIndex("_ID")), plotstore.getString(plotstore.getColumnIndex("ADDRESS")));
        OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(addStore, plotstore.getString(plotstore.getColumnIndex("_id")), plotstore.getString(plotstore.getColumnIndex("address")));

        itemizedStoreOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
        storeOverlays.add(itemizedStoreOverlay);
        plotstore.moveToNext();
    }
```

Comment: make sure the lat and lng are int `GeoPoint(int latitudeE6, int longitudeE6) `

Comment: yes I've done that and tried to find the location on google maps with thoose coordinates and they give me the wanted position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't `getColumnIndex` just return the index of the column within the `cursor`, rather than the value at that index?  You seem to be using it correctly for the `id`:

```
plotstore.getString(plotstore.getColumnIndex("_id"))
```

but not for the `lat` and `long`:

```
plotstore.getColumnIndex("lat")
```

Try changing this (and the `"long"`) to:

```
plotstore.getInt(plotstore.getColumnIndex("lat"))
```